# Are the second commas in the two given sentences necessary?

Tags: punctuation, commas

1. Well, now that I'm here **(,)** that's hardly going to be a problem.
2. Actually, come to think of it now **(,)** you could've done that.

Here, are the commas in brackets necessary? Are both the sentences grammatically correct with or without the second commas?

Comment: In the second example, (,) should be replaced with (;).  What is the intended meaning by ...you could have done that?  Is it that you could have thought of it earlier?    The second sentence sounds OK.

Comment: Let's just say "You could have done that" here means something that the listener had the opportunity to do in the past

Comment: Yes, but the point is not that. In the second example, what suits is not comma. "...come to think of it now.' is a clause; so is 'You could have done that.'  These two clauses cannot form a grammatically correct sentence by using a comma. If I am to edit it  I would write, "Actually, come to think of it now . You could've done that." OR, Actually, come to think of it now; you could've done that. 3) Actually, come to think of it now , which you could've done (earlier/ in the past... or so), etc.

Comment: So what you're saying is, with the second sentence, using the second comma is what makes it grammatically incorrect. But if i were to use a period in its stead or a semi colon that would make the sentence grammatically correct again?

Comment: Yes; as I mentioned in the previous comment. But full stop works when the sentences are less connected than in case of semi-colon in which case the sentences marked by it are close in meaning/ sense conveyed.